# spotfire new table from file filtered

Tags: spotfire

I am using spotfire client.

I have identified some records within a data table that I would like to send to a new data table. Is there some way to create a new table with marked or isolated data or using a data limiting expression on the source table? I have had to export my filtered data out and then import it back in but I am hoping there is a more direct way.

Thanks!

Comment: I don't know of a way to do this through the standard UI but I think it'd be possible to loop through your table in Python with the API, create a new datasource with your marked items and then add that data source as a data table. I might give it a whirl on my lunch break and see if it's feasible.

Comment: what are you trying to do that requires a new data table?

Comment: I use spotfire more for quality assurance and auditing. There are cases when I need to extract records that meet certain criteria in order to do analysis on that subset. I know can you do detail visualization,set filtering schemes, use bookmarks and limit data using expression but I have found exporting the items of interest for additional analysis to new table more straightforward. Having a way to do this without having to export a file and bring it back in would make the workflow faster for my purposes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know the restrictions you need to set on your data to identify the records, you can create a second table based on the source data.

Go to the properties of the table / visualization, then go to the Data tab. You have to scroll all the way to the bottom. There you can edit the "Limit data using expression".

You could also create a detailed visualization if you want, but that is only useful if you can quickly identify the records.

Or insert a calculated column (e.g. case statement) and use this column to filter your data.

Comment: So if I "limit data using expression" can I then create a new table of records that only fit that expression? For example if I have a 26 records, each with a field A-Z with no duplicates. How can I create a new table that has only record A-D without having to first filter, then export, then bring the data back in?

Comment: What I would do in this case is duplicate the table, then go to data table properties, Data tab, edit "limit data using expression", and put in the expression: [column_name] < "E" 
or use [column_name] in ("A", "B", "C", "D")
Whichever you find easier